# How to make CORS work on ie11?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, cross-domain, cors, internet-explorer-11

I have a webapp based on the usual architecture of frontend plus a backend-API.

They are on different domains, let's say domain 1 and domain 2.

On IE11 I can't make CORS work.

Here is the context:

- on Chrome all works fine
- IE11 throws the error ***SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.***
- both the API server and the fronend return a P3P header. This header is as follow: 
  ***P3P  CP="NON DSP LAW CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD HIS OUR DEL IND UNI PUR COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC IVD SAM IVA OTC"***

The security option "Allow thrid-party data sources" of Internet Zone has as value "Disabled". I am keeping it because I can't assume that every client is going to switch this option to *Enabled*.

IE11 does not start neither the request, but it stops it before executing it.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I am having exact same problem!